# "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" Selenium ruby bindings

Tags: ruby, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am running a Selenium Webdriver ruby binding automation script. And facing this exception:-

```
Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

I already have implicit wait put at the beginning of script and when I try to search the element using .displayed? it outputs true.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox#, :profile => "default"


browser.manage().window().maximize();
browser.get "https://cameleon-6945--dev.cs11.cloudforce.com"
main_window = browser.window_handle
browser.find_element(name:"username").clear()
browser.find_element(name:"username").send_keys "mycameleon@siemens.com.us.dev"
browser.find_element(name:"pw").send_keys "ab123f67"
browser.find_element(name:"Login").click
browser.find_element(link_text:"Cameleon Quotes").click
puts "\n""\n""\n""\n"
p browser.title
browser.find_element(name:"new").click
puts "\n""\n""\n""\n"
p browser.title


                                                        ###########   QUOTE CREATION INFORMATION MODULE   
# SET QUOTE NAME
browser.find_element(name:"Name").send_keys "Automated Quote  @ "+Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

#NEW ACCOUNT CREATION
browser.find_element(:class => "lookupIcon").click
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles.last)

#VERIFY NEW WINDOW OPENS
p browser.title
#ADD WAIT
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { browser.current_url=='https://cameleon-6945--dev.cs11.cloudforce.com/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkfm=editPage&lknm=CF00NG000000A7lto&lktp=001&lksrch='}

browser.manage.timeouts.page_load = 20


# SET CONTACT
browser.find_element(name:"CF00NG000000A7ltv").send_keys "Abhishek Kulkarni"

# QUOTE EXPIRATION DATE
#browser.find_element(:id =>"00NG000000A7ltO").send_keys "4/1/2018"
browser.find_element(:css,"#ep > div.pbBody > div:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td.dataCol.col02.last > span > span > a").click


                                                        ###########   PROJECT INFORMATION MODULE    ###########

#SET PROJECT / JOB NAME                                                         
browser.find_element(name:"00NZ0000001G35e").send_keys "this should not be same as quote name as per the requirement"                                                       


# SALES TYPE SELECTION
option = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(browser.find_element(:id => "00NZ0000001G368")
)
option.select_by(:text, "Negotiated")

# SALES OFFICE SELECTION
option = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(browser.find_element(:id => "00NZ0000001G35y")
)
option.select_by(:text, "Chicago")

# MARK HAS GREEN BUILDINGS
browser.find_element(name:"00NZ0000001G36I").click

# FACILITY TYPE SELECTION
option = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(browser.find_element(:id => "00NZ0000001G363")
)
option.select_by(:text, "Warehouse")


                                                        ###########   Contract Dates and Terms MODULE    ###########

#Contract Duration SELECTION
option = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(browser.find_element(:id => "00NZ0000001G36N")
)
option.select_by(:text, "1")

# CONTRACT START DATE
browser.find_element(:css,'#ep > div.pbBody > div:nth-child(7) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(4) > div > span > span > a').click
#browser.find_element(:css,'#ep > div.pbBody > div:nth-child(7) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(4) > div > span > span > a').send_keys "4/1/2015" Put here date of our choice

# CONTRACT SIGNED DATE
browser.find_element(:css,'#ep > div.pbBody > div:nth-child(7) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(4) > span > span > a').click
#browser.find_element(:css,'#ep > div.pbBody > div:nth-child(7) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(4) > span > span > a').send_keys "4/8/2015"

#SET CUSTOMER PO 
browser.find_element(:id =>"00NZ0000001G36X").send_keys "customer_po#00258741236547_04/01/2014"

#CUSTOMER PO DATE
browser.find_element(:css,'#ep > div.pbBody > div:nth-child(7) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td.dataCol.col02.last > span > span > a').click
#browser.find_element(:id =>"00NZ0000001G36r").send_keys "4/1/2015"

                                                        ############ SAVE QUOTE BUTTON #################
#SAVE QUOTE
browser.find_element(name:"save").click

#CAPTURE browser title to verify quote is created in prompt
p browser.title

                                                        ############ GO TO OVERVIEW TAB ################

#Adding wait until quote is created and page is ready for content tab click.
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 5)
wait.until { browser.find_element(:id => "j_id0:tabDetailedContent_lbl") }

browser.find_element(:id => "j_id0:tabDetailedContent_lbl").click

browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20 # seconds

iframe = browser.find_element(:id =>'CPQFrame')
browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe) 

browser.find_element(:css,".processBarElement.noSelected").click


#frame.browser.find_element(:css,".processBarElement.noSelected").click

#browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20 # seconds

iframe2 = browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/iframe")

#browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20 # seconds
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe2)

#RESPONSE LEVEL  #Platinum
browser.find_element(:xpath,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a/input').click
#Ok button
browser.find_element(:xpath,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/a/img').click 

#Select Thermographic service
browser.find_element(:xpath =>'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div/div/p').click

#Ok button
browser.find_element(:xpath =>'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/a/img').click

#Equipment Selection - Transformers Dry LV (480v)
browser.find_element(:xpath,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[2]/div/div/p').click

#Ok button for equipment selection
browser.find_element(:xpath =>'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/a/img').click

#WARRANTY radio button (Yes)
browser.find_element(:xpath =>'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input').click

browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 20

#THERMOGRAPHIC SERVICES TASK HOURS
 "\n""\n""\n""\n""\n"
 puts"Test Passed: Found a Input field for Remove transformer" if browser.find_element(:id=> 'tile217_input').displayed?

browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line0 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line0 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').send_keys"4" #Remove Xr from power source value

browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line1 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line1 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').send_keys"1" #Ground primary & secondary of transformer value

browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line2 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line2 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').send_keys"1" #Clean cabinet value

browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line3 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line3 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').send_keys"1" #Perform insulation value

browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line4 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line4 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').send_keys"1" #Perform winding resistance test value

browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line5 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.line.line5 .columnContent.completed.column1 .fpExpValueRow .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector .numeric').send_keys"1.5" 

#Initial Selection Add to Quote button click
browser.find_element(:xpath =>'/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/a[2]/img').click



#Maximize tab by clicking on expand arrows
#wait.until { browser.find_element(:id => 'CPQContentFullScrImg') }
browser.find_element(:css,"html.ext-strict body.hasMotif div#contentWrapper div.bodyDiv table#bodyTable.outer tbody tr td#sidebarCell.sidebarCell a#handlebarContainer.zen span#pinIndicator.indicator").click

browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a/img").click

#Going to IFRAME to click link 'Multi Year'

browser.switch_to.frame(iframe) 
browser.find_element(:xpath,'/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[5]/div[1]//*').click


iframe_multiyear = browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/iframe")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe_multiyear)

#NORMAL_TIME %
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column3 .integer').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column3 .integer').send_keys"70"

#OT %
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column4 .integer').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column4 .integer').send_keys"5"

#DT%
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column5 .integer').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column5 .integer').send_keys"5"

#SD NORMAL_TIME%
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column6 .integer').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column6 .integer').send_keys"5"

#PW NORMAL_TIME%
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column9 .integer').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column9 .integer').send_keys"5"

#PW OT%
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column10 .integer').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column10 .integer').send_keys"5"

#PW DT%
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column11 .integer').clear()
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .tableRight .line.line0 .column11 .integer').send_keys"5"

#Click OK after PW DT%
browser.find_element(:css,'.configurationPage .mainContent .panelBody .tileContent .nestedFormBox_InstNb .myCssClass').click
puts "\n""\n""\n""\n""Will click ok now"

#Open the collapsed view to again click on OK
browser.find_element(:css,'.configurationPage .mainContent .pageBody .combinedBox .configurationBox.keyboardFocus .tileContent .top .center .text').click


puts "\n""\n""\n""\n""Again clicking ok to expand"

puts "\n""\n""\n""\n""Test Passed found OK" if browser.find_element(:xpath,"//img[@src='theme/configuratorSiemensUS/images/btn/btnSet.png']").displayed?
browser.find_element(:xpath,"//img[@src='theme/configuratorSiemensUS/images/btn/btnSet.png']").click

#Yes on radio button for additional Sales Office Uncomment below line to say yes on radio button
#browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .on .textListValueSelector.valueSelector .simpleValueSelectorCollapsedView .radioButtons .description').click

#No on radio button for additonal sales office
browser.find_element(:css,'.formPropertyBoxDefs .on .textListValueSelector.valueSelector .simpleValueSelectorCollapsedView .radioButtons .text.authorized.true.selected .description').click

#Travel time to site in minutes

#browser.find_element(:css,".formProperty.fpMandatory.fpUpdateable .on .collapsedView.Uncompleted .fpColValue .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector  .integer").send_keys"300"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"300"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
#browser.find_element(:css,".formProperty.fpMandatory.fpUpdateable .on .collapsedView.Uncompleted .fpColValue .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector  .integer").send_keys:return

#Total Electrical Engineers

browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"4"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"3"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[9]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"1"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[9]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return


                                                        #TRAVEL & MILEAGE COSTS
#Open Travel Mileage Costs
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div").click

#Total miles to site
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2000"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return

#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]").click
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[9]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return

#Parking, Tolls
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"400"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return

#sleep = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout =>10)
#sleep.until { browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input") }




                                                                #HOTEL COSTS
#Expand hotel costs
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]").click

#Enter number of nights
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").clear()
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return


browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 15


#Number of rooms
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").clear()
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"3"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return

#Local hotel rate
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").clear()
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"100"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return

                                                                #MEAL COSTS

puts "reached meal costs"



#Expand meal costs tab
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]").click                                                               

#Total meal days
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"3"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return


#Total Resources
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"6"
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return                                                               

#Per Diem
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"25"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
                                                                #MISCELLANEOUS Costs

#Expand section
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]").click                                                               

#Airfares
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"500"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return

#Expand hotel costs tab again
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]").click

#Enter number of nights
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").clear()
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
#browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return


#No. of rooms
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"3"

#Local hotel rate
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"100"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return



#Expanding miscell cost tab again 

#No of airtickets
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return



#Rental Cars
#cars = browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2"


#No. of Rental Cars
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return

#Rental Car rate
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"80"
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return

#Hotel rooms
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").click()
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys:return
```

How can such error be resolved?

Thank you in advance.

Abhishek

Comment: Can we see the ruby script?

Comment: Any chance you could tell us whereabouts the exception is being thrown? That's a pretty big script you have there...

Comment: Sorry for that. Its this exception: -

`Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError)`

Error at Line 560 : -

`
#No. of rooms
browser_find_element(:xpath,".......")`

Comment: Any help pls? Am badly stuck as test cannot proceed without these steps.